# Laravel | Passing variable in Notify

Tags: php, laravel, email, notify

I want to send a mail to Notify, it works but when I try to put the variables, It returns that they are undefined. I don't understand how to pass a variable to Notify, I tried to do `->withResult($result)` but it didn't work out.
Here is the controller:

```
    $result = Review::where('user_hash', '=', $data['lname_c'])->where('email', $data['email_c'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    $result->notify(new SendReview());
```

And my SendReview.php notifications:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{

    return $result['invitation_id']; // test to check if variable is passed
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('Test.')
                ->action('Nani', url($url))
                ->line('Thank you');
}
```

There is user_hash and invitation_id in my Review table, I want to pass them to the notify.  When I do `return $result['invitation_id'];` it works. Hope I am understandable, I checked for duplicate questions and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is how they do it in docs.

```
$arr = [ 'foo' => "bar" ];
$result->notify(new SendReview($arr));
```

And in your `SendReview.php`

```
...

protected $arr;

public function __construct(array $arr) {
        $this->arr = $arr;
}

public function toMail($notifiable) {
        // Access your array in here
        dd($this->arr);
}
```

Comment: When I do `dd($notifiable['invitation_id'])` it return the value but I can't do `return $notifiable['invitation_id']`, how can I do it?

Comment: Why do you need to return the $notifiable['owner']? It does not make sense to me at all.

Comment: $notifiable['invitation_id']* sorry

Comment: You dont have to return those ids in toMail() method

Comment: I have to because I need to a button which redirected to _/xxx/$notifiable['invitation_id']/_

Comment: Hold on. You're confusing me. Do you need to pass an array of data to your mail blade template?

Comment: Let me re-explain all, so I have a table review with owner, invitation_id, user_hash etc... I did `$result = Review::where('xx', '=', $xx etc..)` and after `$result->notify(new SendReview());`, In my SendReview notification, I need to do the a button which redirected to the following link: **/xxx/{invitation_id from the $result column}/ and I need to return the $result->invitation_id to do `url(/xxx/{invitation_id}/`

Comment: You can actually build the url in your toMail() method by accessing the notifiable parameter. And if ever you need to access the `invitation_id` after `$result->notify(new SendReview())` you can just get it by using `$result->invitation_id`

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much for helping

Comment: Anytime brother.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `$notifiable` variable in your `Notification` class.

It is an instance of the class to which the notification is being sent. So here your review object is passed as `$notifiable` variable.

You can try to log it as `logger($notifiable)` in `toMail()` method and check its properties.

Answer (score 0):

For people interested in passing an object e.g `$msg_recipient` and sending an email to a specific user from a controller.

**Controller:**

Remember to add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;`

```
 Notification::route('mail',$msg_recipient->email)
                        ->notify(new MsgReceived($msg_recipient));
```

**In your notification __construct**

```
public function __construct($msg_recipient)
    {
        $this->username = $msg_recipient->username;
    }
```

**toMail function**

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $username = $this->username;

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->greeting('Hello, '.$username)
                    ->line('You received a brand new msg!')
                    ->action('View msg', url('/'.$username));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way seems to be:

```
    public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $message = (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting('Hi ' . $this->user->first_name . ',')
        ->subject($this->subject)
        ->line($this->body)
        // ->with(['id' => $this->user->id])
        ->line('')->view((str_contains($this->body, '</html>')) ? 'emails.empty' : 'emails.default');

    $message->viewData['id'] = $this->user->id;
    return $message;
}
```